# Why does Default derived on an enum not apply to references to the enum?

Tags: rust

I have an enum that has `Default` derived on it, say for example:

```rs
#[derive(Copy, Clone, Debug, Default, PartialEq, Eq)]
pub enum Enum<T> {
    #[default] None,
    One(T),
    Two(T),
}
```

`Vec` has methods like `last()` which return an `Option<&T>`. But when I call `unwrap_or_default()` on the `Option<&T>`, I get the following error:

```
22 |     println!("{:?}", v.last().unwrap_or_default());
   |                      ^^^^^^^^ ----------------- required by a bound introduced by this call
   |                      |
   |                      the trait `Default` is not implemented for `&Enum<i8>`
   |
   = help: the trait `Default` is implemented for `Enum<T>`
note: required by a bound in `Option::<T>::unwrap_or_default`
```

I can work around this in one of two ways:

1. Use `unwrap_or()` and provide a reference to the default element manually:

   ```rs
   v.last().unwrap_or(&Enum::None)
   ```
2. Implement Default for `&Enum`.

   ```rs
   impl<'a> Default for &'a Enum2 {
       fn default() -> &'a Enum2 { &Enum2::None }
   }
   ```

But I don't realize why I should have to. Is there a separate trait I should derive to use the tagged default element correctly here?

[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=5c4ed2f62dba4d2d4e7af97862bfc127)

---

Context: the goal was to output "None" if the list was empty and `Enum::Display(val)` from `Some(val)` for the last element, within a sequence of `format` arguments.

```rs
match self.history.last() { None => "None", Some(val) => val }
```

is illegal: the types of the `match` arms must match. Many other options don't work due to `val` being borrowed and `self` not being `Copy`. Defining a separate default for `Enum` was an easily-thought-of option to avoid extra string formatting/allocation.

Comment: I guess you mean "implement `Default` for enum"? Note that your implementation of `Default for &'a Enum` **does** create the global value `Enum::None` somewhere in the executable const variables. Which is probably the reason why it isn't done automatically.

Comment: @Finomnis Oops, yes, I meant Default. Thanks, fixed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What should `Default` return for `&Enum`?

Remember, a reference **must** point to some valid data, and does **not** keep said data alive.

So even if the `Default` implementation would allocate a new object, there is nowhere to keep it alive, because the returning reference wouldn't keep it alive. The only way is to store the default element somewhere globally; and then it would be shared for everyone. Many objects are more complicated and cannot be simply stored globally, because they are not const-initializable. What should happen then?

The fact that a reference does not implement `Default` automatically is intentional and with good reasons. `unwrap_or_default` is simply the wrong function to call if your contained value is a reference. Use `match` or `if let` to extract the value without having to create a fallback value. `unwrap_or` is also a valid choice if you must absolutely have a fallback value, although I don't see how this is easily possible to implement with a reference without falling back to global const values. Which is also fine, if it fits your usecase.

---

In your case, it's of course fine to derive `Default` manually and is probably what I would do if I absolutely had to. But to me, requiring this in the first place is most likely a code smell in the first place.

For enums that are that simple, it's actually an anti-pattern to use a non-mutable reference instead of a value. References are of size `64` in a 64bit system, while an enum of with three simple values is most likely a `8` bits large. So using a reference is an overhead.

So in this case, you can use `copied()` to query the object by-value. This is most likely even faster than querying it by reference.

```rust
#[derive(Copy, Clone, Debug, Default, PartialEq, Eq)]
pub enum Enum<T> {
    #[default]
    None,
    One(T),
    Two(T),
}

fn main() {
    let v: Vec<Enum<u32>> = vec![];

    println!("{:?}", v.last().copied().unwrap_or_default());
}
```

```
None
```

---

Either way, I think the fact that you have this question in the first place indicates that there is an architectural issue in your code.

There are two cases:

- Your enum members all contain valid data; in that case it is always important to distinguish in `.last()` between "one element with some data" and "no element", and falling back to a default wouldn't be viable.
- Your enum has a `None` member, in which case having the `None` element at `.last()` would be identical to having no members. (which is what I suspect your code does). In that case it's pointless to manually define a `None` member, though, simply use the `Option` enum that already exists. That would make your problem trivially solvable; `Option` already implements `Default` (which is `None`) and can propagate the reference to its member via `.as_ref()`:

```rust
#[derive(Copy, Clone, Debug, PartialEq, Eq)]
pub enum EnumContent<T> {
    One(T),
    Two(T),
}

// Option already implements `Default`.
pub type Enum<T> = Option<EnumContent<T>>;

fn main() {
    let mut v: Vec<Enum<u32>> = vec![];
    println!("{:?} -> {:?}", v, v.last().and_then(Option::as_ref));

    v.push(Some(EnumContent::One(42)));
    println!("{:?} -> {:?}", v, v.last().and_then(Option::as_ref));

    v.push(None);
    println!("{:?} -> {:?}", v, v.last().and_then(Option::as_ref));
}
```

```
[] -> None
[Some(One(42))] -> Some(One(42))
[Some(One(42)), None] -> None
```

Comment: It should return `&Enum::None` like it returns `Enum::None` for the non-reference version. I understand why `Default` shouldn't be implemented for other reference types in general, but for enums, the default is already fairly restricted: https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/default/trait.Default.html#enums

Comment: Where should your `Enum::None` be stored that the reference points to? I think you might have a misconception about what `&` means.

Comment: I kind of do get your point, but automatically deriving `Default` for the reference to an enum would **always** create an extra const object as soon as you derive `Default` for the enum. And the compiler shouldn't just randomly create const objects if they aren't required.

Comment: @Zannick Suggested an alternative for your usecase using `.copied()`.

Comment: Why is it bad to emit a small const object? Since it's a hardcoded constant, the compiler will build it into the instructions, or add a constant to the data section. When the style is to put the default element first, it even can be reused for all enums: https://godbolt.org/z/d7bjzsxaq
(I find it interesting that `&Enum::default` is fewer instructions than `Enum::default`.)

Comment: No it won't be a small const object. If your `T` is 1024kb in size, then `None` is also 1024kb in size. The entire enum is always as large as its largest option. And therefore it also won't always build it into its instructions.

Comment: Either way, if your enum is `Copy` anyway, there really isn't any point in bothering with non-mutable references, as described in my answer.

Comment: Oh, I see. I should have tried to add fields to my playground struct. =)

Comment: @Zannick: https://godbolt.org/z/b3x4s79fn here you can see that the generated global object is 4kB in size, which is probably not something the compiler should auto-generate.

Comment: The `.copied()` is a great suggestion I did not know about, thanks for that. Unfortunately, I'm using this within a `Struct<T> where T: Trait` that holds a `Vec<Enum<T>>` and despite deriving `Copy` on `Enum<T> where T: Trait` (`T` is not `Copy` but all variants are using associated types that *are* `Copy`) the compiler is asking for a trait bound that `Enum<T>: Copy` because `T` is not `Copy`. And that would require adding trait bounds in many places. Same problem with match. I will probably just use `unwrap_or()` here for now, my enums are not going to be too big.

Comment: @Zannick If it's `Clone`, you can use `.cloned()` instead. Otherwise, I think I personally would go with `if let Some(val) = v.last() {...} else {...default action...}` in the function where you use it.

Comment: Good catch, `.cloned()` is the way to go (I guess because `T` is `Clone`). `if let` has the same problem causing a copy that doesn't work without the extra trait bound, unless I hoist it outside the call it's in and duplicate that, which is not ideal.

Comment: @Zannick I think the root of your problem is still architectural; I added a section about that to my answer that suggests an architectural change that makes the question irrelevant in the first place.

Comment: The root of the problem is that I am trying to supply this as an argument to `format` so I can print part of my struct rather than all of it, and I cannot write an `if-else` or `match` statement with two different types in the arms, since I want to output "None" if the list is empty and "T" instead of "Some(T)" otherwise. One option is to add a `None` value to the enum that I can use. The other is to indirect through `Enum`'s formatter: `if self.history.is_empty() { String::from("None") } else { self.history.last().unwrap().to_string() }`

Comment: @Zannick That specifically not, use this construct instead:  `if let Some(last) = self.history.last() { last.to_string() } else { String::from("None") }`. Don't `unwrap()` if it isn't necessary. That's exactly what `if let` is for.

Comment: Ok. Still involves an extra `String` allocation, as opposed to providing the `Enum` value itself, but whatever, this code isn't going to be hit often.

Comment: For everything else I'm missing details. I'm not sure what you mean with "passing it to `format`". But I still have the feeling the problem lies elsewhere, not in the code you show here. If you want a custom `Debug` or `Display` implementation, maybe use a newtype wrapper? Not sure. Depends on the details of your code.

Comment: I appreciate the attempt to help me out, but you've answered my question about the default for a reference, and that was what I was mainly interested in. How I can turn the last element of a vector into a string without moving it was the origin of the question, but that, too, is resolved now.